# JavaScript = "js"? Is this valid?

Tags: javascript, html

I inherited a website, I'm trying to serve its content over https, but when I do so I get an error that this "content" is being delivered insecurely.  The certificate and all that good stuff is set up correctly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://domain.com/?dynamic=js"></script>
```

This doesn't seem to actually reference a file.  I've googled but can't find anything to lead me in the right direction.  Can anyone provide some insight, or better yet explain why this leads to the security problem?

Comment: if you put this in you address bar https://domain.com/?dynamic=js  , in chrome as example....it shows something??

Comment: Does the domain in the address bar match the domain in the src exactly?

Comment: HTTP doesn't care about files.  Who cares what is in the URL.  It's the resource returned that matters.

Comment: Well it looks like a regular query string, is this the line that gives you the error

Comment: Maybe do a `wget` or `curl` on `https://domain.com/?dynamic=js` and make sure it's returning valid JavaScript with the correct content type?

Comment: What happens when you curl `http://domain.com/?dynamic=js`?  It may be that your server automatically serves static content via `https` but that certain dynamic URL handlers are only triggered when the protocol is `http`, though ideally it would be the other way around.

Comment: Perfectly valid; are you sure the certificate of `domain.com` is valid?

Comment: Does the error go away if you drop the parameter (`?dynamic=js`) from the URL?

Comment: @j08691 What does the domain matter?

Comment: `https://domain.com/?dynamic=js` should be returning a JS file.  Have you tried going to that location and see what you get back?  The error message is usually related to having a `src` attribute somewhere that isn't using the SSL/TLS protocol, but just plain `http`.  Using Chrome developer inspector or similar, try searching the HTML for `http:` to see if there are any elements not using `https:`.

Comment: @j08691 Ahh okay :) I was just wondering, cause you can easily request a different website's resource, so I was confused

Comment: Thank you all for your input.  I now know a little more about dynamic js and css, but I'm still having troubles with https.  Everything on the page loads securely except the content generated by the dynamic links:
`ran insecure content from http://domain.com/?dynamic=css.`

I tried hard-coding https:// into the url to no avail.  This is a wordpress site using 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/?dynamic=css" />` to generate the dynamic css and js.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is valid so long as https://domain.com/?dynamic=js generates a javascript file.  See this page for more info on dynamic files:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?21617-Dynamic-external-js-scripts-and-css-stylesheets-with-PHP

Comment: Thank you for this link - it helped me understand dynamic js/css.  I posted a follow-up question with more details above - if you have any insight I'd appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome, friend.  Be sure to upvote and accept answers that were helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running under secure connection (https) then all the resources in your domain have to be also serving via https - like images etc... 
check to see if some image is using http: and not https

Comment: "I'm trying to serve its content over https" + `"https://domain.com/?dynamic=js"`

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with the script-tag. You don't actually need a .js-extension for it to be valid, as long as it returns JavaScript the browser will be happy.

Also, this line has nothing to do with the HTTPS-error you're getting. You should make sure that ALL the content linked on that page is delivered through HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

Make sure ALL of the assets on the page are served up with relative paths.  Images. css. scripts, etc.. Then they will load no matter if you are on https or not.

Relative = `"/images/test.jpg"` instead of `"http://test.com/images/test.jpg"`

Also can do Protocol relative url : `"//test.com/images/test.jpg"` (Thanks to commenter)

Comment: Or just a protocol relative URL like `//test.com/images/test.jpg`